# Convert a range of numbers to portion of 100

Tags: javascript

I have a list of numbers (any length) ranging from 0 - 100, including duplicates. I need convert those numbers to portions of 100.

For example:
[25, 50] becomes [33.333, 66.666]

[25, 50, 50] becomes [20, 40, 40]

What algorithm would work best for this?

Comment: Do you just want another array filled with these calculations at the same index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to calculate the sum of the values in your array - then you could divide each value in your array by that sum, and multiply by 100.

Comment: That's more likely :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
console.log(33.333 - 33.333 % 25); // 50
```

% is MODULO operator.

```
Number.prototype.range = function(a) {
    return this - this % a;
}

console.log((33.333).range(25)); // 25;
console.log((66.666).range(25)); // 50;
```

In array use map like this :

```
console.log([33.333, 66.666].map(function(a) {
    return a.range(25);
}));
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vuzuhuma/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by calculating the sum of the array and then dividing each value by that. It can be done easily using `Array.reduce` to sum and `Array.map` to create a new array with the final output. Here is an example:

```
var arr1 = [25, 50];
var arr2 = [25, 50, 50];

function proportion(arr) {
  var sum = arr.reduce(function(prev, cur){
    return prev + cur;
  });

  var result = arr.map(function(val){
    return (val/sum)*100;
  });

  return result;
}


console.log(proportion(arr1)); // [33.33333333333333, 66.66666666666666]
console.log(proportion(arr2)); // [20, 40, 40]
```

JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/texuc/1/edit

Comment: Got to love the 'tactical down voter' two seconds after I post my answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this is to sum the array, find each value as a fraction of that sum, and then multiply by 100.

This code should do the trick.

```
var inputArray = [25, 50, 50];
var outputArray = [];
var total = 0;

for (var i=0; i<(inputArray.length); i++) {
    total += inputArray[i];
}
for (var i=0; i<(inputArray.length); i++) {
    outputArray[i] = ((inputArray[i])/total) * 100;
}
```